# Returning JSONP for a Suspended Atmosphere request

Tags: java, json, jsonp, jax-rs, atmosphere

I have a servlet that has a suspending method and a broadcasting one:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/notification")
  @Produces( { "application/x-javascript", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  @Suspend
  public JSONWithPadding getNextNotification(
    @QueryParam("callback") @DefaultValue("callback") String callback) {

    Random random = new Random();

    Notification n = new Notification();
    n.setMessage("Message is " + Long.toHexString(random.nextLong()));
    n.setMessage("S-" + Long.toHexString(random.nextLong()));

    return new JSONWithPadding(n, callback);

  }
```

I invoke this from a browser and see the following nice output in my browser:

```
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------- http://github.com/Atmosphere ------------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
<!-- Welcome to the Atmosphere Framework.....
<!-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<!-- EOD -->callback({"message":"S-c897404ad5703dcc","sender":null}
```

So my object is nicely serialized to JSONP.

Now I call my broadcaster method:

```
  @Context Broadcaster bc;

  @Broadcast({JsonpFilter.class})
  @GET
  @Path("/broadcast5")
  public Broadcastable broadcast5() {
    Random random = new Random();
    Notification n = new Notification();
    n.setMessage("Message is " + Long.toHexString(random.nextLong()));
    n.setMessage("S-" + Long.toHexString(random.nextLong()));
    return new Broadcastable(new JSONWithPadding(n, "callback111"), bc);
  }
```

On the server side I get the following exception and nothing is broadcasted:

```
[#|2012-01-19T17:28:30.483+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_Thr
eadID=20;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080(5);|StandardWrapperValve[AtmosphereServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for s
ervlet AtmosphereServlet threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Throwable
        at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor.onRequest(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:154)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:219)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:154)
        at org.atmosphere.container.GrizzlyCometSupport.service(GrizzlyCometSupport.java:103)
        at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishWebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishWebSocketSupport.java:101)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doCometSupport(AtmosphereServlet.java:1212)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:1171)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:1157)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:444)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:308)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:94)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Throwable
        at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.doFilter(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.invokeFilterChain(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:116)
        at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor$FilterChainServletWrapper.service(ReflectorServletProcessor.
java:293)
        at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor.onRequest(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:151)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.atmosphere.commons.jersey.JsonpFilter.filter(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/
Object;)Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/BroadcastFilter$BroadcastAction;
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.BroadcasterConfig.filter(BroadcasterConfig.java:447)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.filter(DefaultBroadcaster.java:890)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.broadcast(DefaultBroadcaster.java:875)
        at org.atmosphere.jersey.AtmosphereFilter$Filter.broadcast(AtmosphereFilter.java:632)
        at org.atmosphere.jersey.AtmosphereFilter$Filter.filter(AtmosphereFilter.java:468)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1416)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.doFilter(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:155)
        ... 44 more
|#]
```

How could I make my broadcaster work? Do I need to return `JSONWithPadding` object or only the POJO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an AbstractMethodError. Do you have atmosphere-commons on your classpath?

Comment: I removed it and now the stacktrace changed to: `Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.BroadcasterConfig.filter(BroadcasterConfig.java:447)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.filter(DefaultBroadcaster.java:890)`

Comment: I threw out every jar and put only those from the official samples. This way came atmosphere-samles-commons.jar and the problem changed. Now I receive `com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONWithPadding@180ce9c` in the client, so only serialization is missing now :-)